# request not showing data with body-parser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, body-parser

I am sending some JSON object from my AngularJS client to my NodeJS server.

Here is my client code making a POST request.

```
customerData.endPoint = "customers";
$http.post('https://woocommerce-api-samarthagarwal-1.c9users.io/api', customerData)
     .then(function(response){
          console.log(response)
      });
```

Here is my server code.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

var urlParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true});
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/api', jsonParser, function(request, response){
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log("body " + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    var endPoint = request.body.endPoint;
    console.log("POST on " + endPoint + " with Data " + (request.body.customer));
    });


var port = process.env.PORT;
var ip = process.env.IP
app.listen(port, ip,  function () {
  console.log('Server listening on ' + ip +':' + port);
});
```

But nothing is logged to the console.

[image: Console]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you log request.headers? Looks like you are not getting Content-Type: application/json which prevents bodyParser.json to parse the request

Comment: I get `'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'` in the request headers log.

Comment: Set that request header to `"application/json"` on the Angular side. It's what tells your server (i.e. the parser) that it's sending a JSON payload.

Comment: That is why you don't get the body, what if you call with curl? curl -X POST -d '{ "endPoint": "customers"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://woocommerce-api-samarthagarwal-1.c9users.io/api

Comment: The `cUrl`showed up the `customers` on the server. Can I use a middleware to add that header to every request? Actually I am getting a preflight error if I am adding headers to my Angular Code.

Comment: I got it working by adding header manually to every request by using a middleware. Thanks for figuring it out guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the header manually for every request using a middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.headers['content-type'] = "application/json";
    next();
});
```

I used this code just after all the requires. **This should be the first middleware to work.** I hope it helps some people like myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the `bodyParser` as middleware with express otherwise it won't know how to parse the body. This middleware needs to come before any routes are defined.

Without registering `bodyParser` as middleware, your `request.body` will always be `{}`. So when doing `request.body.customer`, the value will be `undefined` and your entire `console.log()` statement won't print to the console.

[Example of body-parser usage from docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});

app.post('/api', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log("body " + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
    var endPoint = req.body.endPoint;
    console.log("POST on " + endPoint + " with Data " + (req.body.customer));
});


var port = process.env.PORT;
var ip = process.env.IP
app.listen(port, ip,  function () {
  console.log('Server listening on ' + ip +':' + port);
});
```

Comment: This is how to use `body-parser` so make sure it actually installed correctly, `npm install --save body-parser`

Comment: I reinstalled and updated the code with yours. Still getting `{}` for `JSON.stringify(request.body)`.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal I cleaned up your route and updated my answer with it. See if that helps.

Comment: I think you are not receiving the Content-Type: application/json header

Comment: Can I use a middleware to add the header on every request?